# Dependency Injection - How can I make a class dynamical in a constructor of a service in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I tried to find a solution but my knowledge of DI in services is still to little to make this thing working - so I'm wondering if there is a way to make this work at all?

My setup: I do have a shared Downloadservice which gets data from another service and then provides a link to download the blob as a pdf file. My code works fine when I inject only one source but what I want to do is: The Downloadservice should be generic depending on which component requires its function. This means the passed in data in its constructor has to be dynamically.

This is an excerpt of my code:

```
constructor(private dataservice: MusicService) { }

  onDownload() {
    this.dataservice.getDownloadData().subscribe(
    (data) => {
      const fileName = 'Report.pdf';
      const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
        } else {
          const link = document.createElement('a');
          if (link.download !== undefined) {
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.setAttribute('href', url);
            link.setAttribute('download', fileName);
            link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

All of my services that will be injected do have the getDownloadData()-Method.
So the only line I have to make dynamically is:

```
constructor(private dataservice: MusicService) { }
```

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you has a generalService

```
dataService:any=null
getData()
{
   this.dataService?return this.http.get(...):of(null)
}
```

You can has in a component

```
constructor(private musicService:MusicService,private generalService:GeneralService){
   this.generalService.dataService=this.MusicService
}
ngOnInit()
{
 this.generalService.getData().subscribe(...)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I could not get it working like that since my service had several other dependencies. But it helped me to find the way to a solution. Now I'm working with an abstract class. So I appreciate you taking time for that.